# Buidling classes with user input and calling methods

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x

Learned alot in this first week, following PCC, but biggest leaps came from the community and others giving their time to help, thank you!

All input appreciated!

**Objective**
Goals were to fill a class with user inputs from multiple users and then be able to call methods to each user input created class. (... did I say that right O.o)

**Code**

```
class User():
    def __init__(a, first_name, last_name, city, age):
        a.first_name = first_name.title()
        a.last_name = last_name.title()
        a.city = city.title()
        a.age = age

    def describe_user(a):
        print("-----")
        print("First Name" + " : " + a.first_name)
        print("Last Name" + " : " + a.last_name)
        print("City" + " : " + a.city)
        print("Age" + " : " + a.age)

def ask_user(message=''):
    user_input = ''
    while not user_input:
        user_input = input(message)
    return user_input

def form_complete(values, placement, length):
    placement = []
    while len(placement) < length:
        first_name = ask_user("Enter First Name: ")
        last_name =  ask_user("Enter Last Name: ")
        city = ask_user("Enter City: ")
        age = ask_user("Enter Age: ")
        values = User(first_name, last_name, city, age)
        placement.append(values)
    return placement

if __name__ == '__main__':

    users = form_complete('user', 'users', 3)
    for a in range(len(users)):
        users[a].describe_user()
```

**Output**

```
xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/9$ python3 3.py
Enter First Name: vash
Enter Last Name: the stampede
Enter City: gunsmoke
Enter Age: 131
Enter First Name: spike
Enter Last Name: spiegel
Enter City: mars
Enter Age: 27
Enter First Name: holden
Enter Last Name: caulfield
Enter City: new york city
Enter Age: 16
-----
First Name : Vash
Last Name : The Stampede
City : Gunsmoke
Age : 131

Greetings Vash!
-----
First Name : Spike
Last Name : Spiegel
City : Mars
Age : 27

Greetings Spike!
-----
First Name : Holden
Last Name : Caulfield
City : New York City
Age : 16

Greetings Holden!
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/9$
```

Comment: @peilonrayz learned about classes today, tried applying somethings we discussed, I feel I was able to capture some things you taught me, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Python has something called magic methods (sometimes also called dunder methods, but the other name is way cooler).

These methods have special names and enable custom classes to use built-in functionality. If, for example you write a custom numeric class, you would want to be able to do e.g. `a + b`, with at least one of them being an instance of your class (and the other one either as well or even just a plain number). In order to achieve this, you would just implement an appropriate `__add__` method for your class.

[Here is a good list](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) going through all available magic methods.

In your class, we can use the `__str__` method. It gets used when you call `str(obj)`, `print(obj)`, `"{}".format(obj)` (unless you also implement the `__format__` method):

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, city, age):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.city = city
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        s = ["-----",
             f"First Name : {self.first_name}",
             f"Last Name : {self.last_name}",
             f"City : {self.city}",
             f"Age : {self.age}"]
        return "\n".join(s)
```

Note that I made some more changes:

- The empty parenthesis after the class name are not needed. You only need parenthesis if you want to inherit from some other class.
- I also called the first argument of the methods `self`, which is the customary name for it in Python.
- I did not build the string using simple addition, since that is quite slow in Python (strings are immutable objects, so each string addition involves creating a new string of the right length and copying the content of the two strings being added).
- And finally, I used [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) to make the formatting a bit easier.

---

In your `form_complete` function (which IMO should be called `complete_form`, since that describes an action), you could use a list comprehension:

```
def complete_form(n_users):
    return [User(ask_user("Enter First Name: ").title(),
                 ask_user("Enter Last Name: ").title(),
                 ask_user("Enter City: ").title(),
                 ask_user("Enter Age: ", type=int)
            for _ in range(n_users)]
```

Note that I moved the alls to `str.title` here, since it should be the responsibility of the user of your class to pass in correct values (for example, what if your user enters a name for which `title()` does not make sense? There are also names that start with lowercase letters. Etc...)

I also removed `values` and `placement` from the signature, since you override them right away anyways.

---

And finally, I added a keyword argument to `ask_user`, which allows you to validate that age is actually an integer:

```
def ask_user(message='', type=str):
    user_input = ''
    while not user_input:
        try:
            user_input = type(input(message).strip())
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return user_input
```

By default, this just calls the `str` function on whatever your user supplied. If you instead specify `type=int`, it will call `int` on the input, which raises a `ValueError` if it cannot parse the input it received as an `int`.

This has only one weakness right now: If the user wants to enter something that parses as `0`, they are stuck in an infinite loop (so no users under the age of 1 allowed).

I also added a call to `str.strip`, so user names like  (space) and  (tab) are not allowed either.

Comment: amazing, its like my python learning book gets a new chapter each time you respond, I'm going to review this, and learn it. Again it really is an understatement, how valuable a tool it is to have people like you that aren't hoarding knowledge and check in on us beginners and boost us. Thank you so much, I was super anxious for a response to learn from yesterday, I have been awake for 5 minutes now this was the first thing I checked ha This made my day so far